# How to port forward automatically in java?

Tags: java, server, port, portforwarding

I know that bit torrent clients use automatic port forwarding (Port forwarding with having to configure the router) so that they can connect to each other. I want the users in my application to be able to host a server without having to configure the router. So I was wondering how you would do so in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use UPnP (Universal Plug and Play) port forwarding. One library mentioned is [Cling](https://github.com/4thline/cling), but there's much simpler library - [WaifUPnP](https://fdossena.com/?p=waifupnp/index.frag), which allows you to forward a port with just one line like:

```
UPnP.openTCP(portnumber);
```

Comment: Just a bit of the warning, WaifUPnP is licensed under LGPL.

Answer (score 1):

UPnP is your friend.  It is a standardized method which allows automatically configuring routers to forward ports.  There are a couple of different ways to do it.  One package that supports UPnP under Java is Cling.  http://4thline.org/projects/cling/

Answer (score 1):

UPnP protocol can handle the automatic port forwarding. 
Try this library (Cling - Java/Android UPnP library and tools):
http://4thline.org/projects/cling/