# ServerSocket tcp server on pc unreachable by Android phone client

Tags: java, server, timeout, client, serversocket

hope someone can help.  I'm just trying to get a TCP socket connection working between a Windows pc server and an android phone.  Firstly, how to determine what ip address is needed.  I have ATT UVerse Broadband and my pc is connected to its box via ethernet.  According to ATT:

https://www.att-services.net/tools/tool-ip-address-hostname.html

I have one ip addr: 162.192.62.91.  According to ipconfig, I have another: 192.168.1.67.  Both time out calling accept() on the ServerSocket, whether the client is started up shortly after the call or not.  Which do I need anyway?  Netstat accurately reflects the presence of the server listener until the server code is terminated and then reflects its absence.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Windows Firewall is currently off.  Thanks to anyone who will give it a look. Here's the java server:

```
package my.server;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServerSocket {
    static ServerSocket server;
    static String addr = "192.168.1.67";
    static int port = 8080;
    InetAddress ia;
    private MyServerSocket() throws Exception {
        if (addr != null && !addr.isEmpty()) {
            ia = InetAddress.getByName(addr);  //ipAddress);
            System.out.println("18 MSS InetAddress.getByName(" + addr + ") = " + ia);
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, ia);
                System.out.println("20 MSS Nonempty ipAddress: instantiated ServerSocket");
            } catch( IOException e) {
                System.out.println("22 MSS while instantiating ServerSocket: " + e);
            }
        }
        else { 
            ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            server = new ServerSocket(port, 1, ia);
            System.out.print("28 MSS empty ipAddress: MSS new ServerSocket port ");
            System.out.print(port);
            System.out.println(", addr " + ia);
        }
    }

    private void listen() throws Exception {
        String data = null;
        Socket client = server.accept();  //Hangs here
        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("35 MSS New connection from " + clientAddress);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));        
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
           System.out.println("40 MSS Message from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyServerSocket app = new MyServerSocket();
        System.out.println("52 MSS instantiated MyServerSocket: " + 
                " Addr=" + server.getInetAddress() + 
                " Port=" + server.getLocalPort());

        app.listen();
    }
}
```

Android Client:

```
package my.androidsocket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class AndroidClientSocket extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ClientSocket";
    static InputStream is = null;
    private String serverHostOrIPAddr = "192.168.1.67"; //162.192.62.91 (can't assign addr)
        //127.0.0.1 (refused) "listening on port 3306 (mysql) for local loopback only"
        //192.168.1.67 (times out w an Exception) (from cmd->ipconfig-> ip4 address)
    private String serverPortStr = "8080";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer serverPort = Integer.parseInt(serverPortStr);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"24 ACS connecting to host " + serverHostOrIPAddr +
                                                " on port " + serverPort + ".");
        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            //hangs, then returns null even when server is listening to the addr/port at startup
            socket = new Socket(serverHostOrIPAddr, serverPort);

            System.out.print("33 ACS Socket instantiation returned ");
            System.out.println(socket);

            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            String userInput = "a\r\n";
            while (true) {
                System.out.print("client: ");
                //String userInput = stdIn.readLine();
                /** Exit on 'q' char sent */
                if ("q".equals(userInput)) {
                    break;
                }
                out.println(userInput);  //out to console
                userInput = "";
                System.out.println("server: " + in.readLine());  //chars from server
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"55 ACS while connecting to host " + serverHostOrIPAddr + ": " + e );
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"59 ACS while closing socket " + e );
            }
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"63 ACS while connecting to host: " + e);
            if(socket!=null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"68 ACS while closing socket: " + e);
                }
            }
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String userInput = "user input...\r\n";  //Fake the user console input
        out.println(userInput);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"76 ACS user input sent to socket output stream: " + userInput);
        out.close();

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"82 ACS IOException closing input stream: " + e);
        }
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"87 ACS IOException closing socket: " + e);
        }
        return "null";
    }

}
```

and Android caller:

```
package my.androidsocket;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AndroidClientSocket acs = new AndroidClientSocket( );
        acs.execute();

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("18 MA GET response: " + "null");
    }
}
```

And output:

```
18 MSS InetAddress.getByName(192.168.1.67) = /192.168.1.671
20 MSS Nonempty ipAddress: instantiated ServerSocket: port=8080 bindAddr=/192.168.1.67
```

Comment: Which network your phone is connected to(your home wifi, mobile internet , etc)?

Comment: mobile internet which AT&T appears to call a wireless data plan.

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to bind to either

- the specific IPv4 address of the network adapter that is connected to your LAN router (in your case, `192.168.1.67`).
- `0.0.0.0`, which binds to all local IPv4 networks that the PC is connected to.

When the phone is connected to a mobile network, it must connect to your public Internet IPv4 address, as assigned by your ISP (in your case, `162.192.62.91`).

Since your PC gets its Internet connection from a LAN router, you need to also enable port forwarding in the router's configuration so it can pass inbound traffic from the router's public WAN IP:port to a LAN IP:port that your server is bound to.  **You are likely missing this step.**

If your router supports uPNP and it is enabled, your server code can configure the port forwarding dynamically when needed (see [How to port forward automatically in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951467/)).  Otherwise, you have to log into your router directly and configure it statically as needed.

When the phone is connected to the same LAN as the PC, it can connect to any LAN IPv4 address that the server is bound to.

Comment: Hi and thanks so much for the response.  I changed the addr in the Android client to 162.192.62.91 and left the server addr the same as I believe you suggest.  I've imported WaifUPnP.jar in the server project and added  UPnP.openPortTCP(8080);  as the first line in its main();  I can instantiate a UPnP object, but calls to any of its members only return null.  I called up ATT tech support asking for any guidance on port forwarding.  He told me that he had just set me up for port forwarding and that I am good to go, whatever that meant.  Tried again.  Same thing far as I can tell. Still hangs

Comment: Oops wait, I've made some progress.  Think I've got it now.  And yes, I think ATT helped.  I just changed both to the 162 address and it works.  Thanks for clearing my logjam.

Comment: You should not have contacted AT&T, this is not their problem to solve. And you can't bind your TCP server to your public IP unless your PC is connected *directly* to your Internet modem, which is clearly not the case here since your PC has a LAN IP assigned to it. As for uPNP, did you verify that your router even supports uPNP? It is usually NOT enabled by default. Go into your router settings to verify. As this issue is more a networking problem than a coding problem, you should ask about it over on [sf].

Comment: I'd tried changing both to the 162 address earlier and it didn't work, until I called ATT.  Told em I needed port forwarding.  Rep said, 'Port forwarding.  I'll have it ready for you in a jiffy.'  And the next time I tried... voala!

Comment: @TedJackson AT&T (or any ISP, for that matter) cannot configure your LAN router's port forwarding rules for you, as they don't have access to your router (unless the router is built-in to your modem, and they provided the modem and have remote admin access to it). But, they might have done something on their end to prevent blocking inbound TCP connections from reaching your modem and thus the LAN router, so it then has a change to forward the connections to your server PC.  Again, not a programming issue.