# Add iptables programmatically using Java for port forwarding

Tags: java, networking, tcp, portforwarding, nat

Is there any method (using java.net package or some protocol) that could be used by Java based client application in intranet to map port to the residential gateway(router)'s iptable to enable access from internet? I noticed some chat app could add a range of ports to router automatically for port forwarding.I am not sure if pure java app could make it or not. Or have to use libiptc + JNI to realize this function?

Comment: What makes you think the routers use iptables? That is a host thing.

Comment: Can you describe what you’re hoping to achieve? As in, why do you think you need to programmatically forward ports to begin with?

Comment: What i saw is my the residential gateway(router) could enable port forwarding by add ports and in/out ip addresses. and I also found some chat app's port is also in the list. So if I want to write a tcp/ip based application and could communicating in not only my intranet but also internet, I just want to know how I could made this happen programmatically. also I want to know if I could use java to make it done?

Comment: You should probably better look at UPnP and not at iptables. Does this answer your question? [How to port forward automatically in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951467/how-to-port-forward-automatically-in-java)

Comment: Thank you. Steffen Ullrich. I'll check.